# Extract strings from text files and rename them accordingly in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a lot of text file named randomly (something like 70000 files); all I know is that somewhere in the first 30 lines there are two lines of the format `Author: Samuel Richardson` and another line `Title: Clarissa, Volume 5 (of 9)`. I am not sure of the case of these two lines.

I want to extract the title and the author and rename the file accordingly, something like `"Clarissa, Volume 5 (of 9) ,___, Samuel Richardson.txt"` (I use `,___,` so that there are valid separators between author and titles.

My code is

```
for filename in *.txt; do

    title=$(head -n 30 $filename.txt | grep -i 'Title:' | sed -n 's/^.*Title: //p')
    author=$(head -n 30 $filename.txt | grep -i 'Author:' | sed -n 's/^.*Author: //p')
    new_name="$title ,___, $author"

    mv $filename $new_name.txt
done
```

It is not working as expected. The subcode

```
echo "title: $title _"
echo "author: $author _"

new_name="$title ,___, $author"

echo $new_name
```

prints as output the following

```
 _tle: Clarissa, Volume 5 (of 9)
 _thor: Samuel Richardson
 ,___, Samuel Richardson)
```

Moreover, I don't know how to save the computation of the extraction of the first 30 lines with the `head` command to a variable `firstlines`, so that it should not be re-computated.

The code

```
firstlines=$(head -n 30 randomname.txt)
```

and the use of `title=$($firstlines | grep -i 'Title:' | sed -n 's/^.*Title: //p')`

prints out the error `command not found`.

Comment: Quick guess... check line endings, they are probably Windows style.

Comment: There's a possibility of massive confusion and maybe data loss if this goes wrong. I'd recommend using `mv -n` or `mv -i` to avoid overwriting files by accident, and making a backup of everything beforehand would be a really good idea.

Comment: Looping calling `head` twice, `grep` twice and `sed` twice with 4-pipes and 2 *command substitutions* is horribly inefficient (and will take forever on large data sets). Instead, simply use either `awk` or `sed` for the entire thing. A simple `sed -n '/^\(Author:\|Title:\)/p' file` will find the two lines beginning with `"Author:"` or `"Title:"` allowing you to remove both leaving only the wanted information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Poshi's comment about about line endings is correct, and @B.Shefter's answer is on the right track but has a number of problems (unquoted variable references, relying on nonstandard features of `echo` and `sed`), so I thought I'd rewrite with (hopefully) the problems fixed.

Also, I'll repeat the recommendation I gave in a comment: use `mv -n` or `mv -i` to avoid overwriting files if anything goes wrong, and make a backup first. (You have a backup anyway, right? You should *always* have a backup of anything you don't want to lose.)

Anyway, here's my take on it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.txt; do

    # Grab the first 30 lines with carriage returns removed:
    firstlines=$(head -n 30 "$filename" | tr -d '\r')

    # Capture the title and author. Note that sed doesn't have case-insensitive
    # patterns, so use e.g. [Tt] to manually make them case-insensitive. Also, use
    # [[:blank:]]* to allow any number of spaces and/or tabs after the ":".
    title=$(echo "$firstlines" | sed -n 's/^.*[Tt][Ii][Tt][Ll][Ee]:[[:blank:]]*//p')
    if [ -z "$title" ]; then
        echo "Unable to find Title: in $filename; skipping" >&2
        continue
    fi

    author=$(echo "$firstlines" | sed -n 's/^.*[Aa][Uu][Tt][Hh][Oo][Rr]:[[:blank:]]*//p')
    if [ -z "$author" ]; then
        echo "Unable to find Author: in $filename; skipping" >&2
        continue
    fi

    new_name="$title ,___, $author.txt"

    # Note: the filenames here will contain spaces, so double-quoting is *critical*
    mv -i "$filename" "$new_name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

@Poshi's right: your main issue is line endings. It looks as if each line ending includes a carriage return (`\r`). By itself, `\r` just moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. When coupled with `\n` it works fine--because it moves to the beginning of the *next* line--but by itself it causes what you're seeing: some text, followed by the cursor going back to the beginning of the line, followed by more text overwriting what was there originally.

**EDIT:** It would probably help if I included a solution for that. Something like this should work, inserted before the assignment to `new_name`:

```
title=$(echo -e $title | sed 's/\r//')
author=$(echo -e $author | sed 's/\r//')
```

As for your second problem, the reason you're getting `command not found` is that the first word in the variable `$firstlines` isn't a command. You want something like:

```
title=$(echo -e $firstlines | grep -i 'Title:' | sed -n 's/^.*Title: //p')
```